# ESPA-API for Landsat scene downloads

Tags: api, landsat, landsat-8

I've been trying to automatically download Landsat scenes with espa-api ( https://github.com/USGS-EROS/espa-api)

However I'm having a big issue with this api right now, that is the long waiting time between ordering and having the data available for download, even for level 1 products, which shouldn't take so long (don't require any additional processing).

Does anybody have any tips regarding this issue? Is there any way to speed up this downloading time, at least for level1 products?

Any other useful landsat ingestion api would be useful as well. I've been using landsat-util but unfortunately the download api is broken right now with the Collection 1 updates.